# Problem installing opendmarc

Tags: mail-server

I am trying to install opendmarc on an Ubuntu 18.04.5 server.

During apt-get install opendmarc I get:

> Job for opendmarc.service failed because the control process exited
> with error code. See "systemctl status opendmarc.service" and
> "journalctl -xe" for details. invoke-rc.d: initscript opendmarc,
> action "start" failed. ● opendmarc.service - OpenDMARC Milter
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/opendmarc.service; disabled;
> vendor preset: enabled)    Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result:
> exit-code) since Thu 2020-10-08 09:58:18 UTC; 13ms ago
> Docs: man:opendmarc(8)
> man:opendmarc.conf(5)   Process: 9643 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendmarc (code=exited, status=127)

I tried installing libopendmarc-dev and got the same

If I try to run opendmarc I get:

> opendmarc: error while loading shared libraries: libopendmarc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

It appears I don't have libopendmarc.so.2. I assumed it would be installed with libopendmarc-dev but apparently not.

How can I install it?

Comment: You may have a `libopendmarc.so` , probably somewhere in `/usr/lib`. In that same directory, create a symbolic link from `libopendmarc.so` to `libopendmarc.so.2` and try again. This happens all the time (I don't know why).

Comment: Thanks. I hadonly  libopendmarc.a in /usr/lib but creating a link from that to libopendmarc.so.2 results in:
opendmarc: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libopendmarc.so.2: invalid ELF header

Answer (score 0):

Solved by purging opendmarc, libopendmarc-dev, and also libopendmarc2 which I had previously overlooked, and then re-installing opendmarc, libopendmarc-dev and libopendmarc2 again.

This gave me the following symlinks in /usr/lib:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     21 Oct  1 12:51 libopendmarc.so.2 -> libopendmarc.so.2.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  47784 Oct  1 12:51 libopendmarc.so.2.0.2
```